# Do you lose the 15 pts if someone later unaccepts your answer?

Tags: discussion, reputation, accepted-answer

Do you lose the 15 pts if someone later unaccepts your answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you do lose points.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, and unfortunately this is one of the instances where it's quite difficult to determine exactly *which* answer you lost the points for. The best way I know of is to keep a page open containing a list of your accepted answers (from the envelope page, for example), and compare it to the post-unaccepted status page.

Comment: Since September 2011, users are [notified](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105309/how-do-you-want-to-be-notified-of-unaccepted-answers) of unaccepts.