# If your answer is unaccepted after becoming Community Wiki, do you still lose 15 rep for it?

Tags: discussion, reputation, community-wiki

If your answer is accepted while it's not [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) (CW), but is later unaccepted after becoming CW, do you still lose 15 rep for it?

I checked the answer in [How do questions marked community wiki AFTER you answer impact rep upon recalc](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16750/how-do-questions-marked-community-wiki-after-you-answer-impact-rep-upon-recalc), but it only talks about votes. The FAQ on [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) talks about how rep will not be affected from vote removals after an answer becomes a CW post, but it doesn't say anything about unaccepting an answer.

I've also checked out some other posts on this topic, including

- [Do you lose the 15 pts if someone later unaccepts your answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42241/do-you-lose-the-15-pts-if-someone-later-unaccepts-your-answer)
- [What are all the ways to gain/lose rep if all your posts are CW?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31865/what-are-all-the-ways-to-gain-lose-rep-if-all-your-posts-are-cw)

but I haven't been able to find any answers to my question in those either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your answer is unaccepted after it's made community wiki, you do not *immediately* lose the 15 rep.  It will, however, be lost when your rep is recalc'ed.

This also goes for up/down votes affecting rep before a post is made wiki, but are deleted after wiki-fication.

We'll look at cleaning this vote deletion code up.

Comment: I always thought you kept the points you got before it was made CW, that really sucks.  Does that mean that bobince lost [all those points](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)?

Comment: @Lance - you keep the points on active (i.e. undeleted) votes that were placed before a post is made CW.  We're talking about votes that are deleted and should immediately remove their rep grants, but don't due to CW status.