# How does Stack Overflow deal with reputation when I remove an accepted answer after it turn into CW mode

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, community-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If your answer is unaccepted after becoming Community Wiki, do you still lose 15 rep for it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96675/if-your-answer-is-unaccepted-after-becoming-community-wiki-do-you-still-lose-15)

I want to know how Stack Overflow deal with reputation in the very special case. As follows:

1. I chose an accepted answer in my question. and the answer's owner get 15 reputation and I get 2 reputation.
2. The answer turn into Community wiki mode.
3. Then someone provides a better answer, so I canceled the accepted answer.

After I canceled the accepted answer, How does Stack Overflow deal with the owner's 15 reputation?

This FAQ page wasn't description the case. [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

Comment: Why not try it and see?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96675/if-your-answer-is-unaccepted-after-becoming-community-wiki-do-you-still-lose-15   this question can answer it.